# Syntax error appears, but weird suggestion?

Tags: java, methods, compiler-construction

```
import java.utils.Scanner; 

public class PD {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 

    System.out.print("Enter your number: " ); 
    int number = input.nextInt(); 
    System.out.println( DPPP(number) + "is double palidromic prime"); 

    }
    // main method checks every other method and returns a value that follows everything
    public static int DPPP( int number) {
        int count = 2;
            while (count < number) {
                String blank = "";
                String Snumber = count + blank; 
                if (isPalindromic(count) && isPrime(count) && 
                    isPalindromic(Snumber.length()) && isPrime(Snumber.length()))
                    return count;
                    count++;
            }
    }

    // method to find palindromic 
    public static boolean isPalindromic(int number) {
        String blank = ""; 
        String convert = count + blank; 
            for (int i = 0, int q = 1; i <= (convert.length()/2 - 1); i++, q++) { 
                if (convert.substring(i,q) == number.substring(number.length() - q, number.length() - i))
                    return true;
                else 
                    return false; 
        }
    }
    // method to find prime
    public static boolean isPrime(int number) {
        for (int divisor = 2; divisor <= number/2; divisor++) { 
            if (number % divisor == 0) { 
                return false; 
            }
        }
        return true; 
    }
}
```

Error:

```
PD.java:28: <identifier> expected
for (int i = 0, int q = 1; i <= (convert.length()/2 - 1); i++, q++) { 
               ^
PD.java:28: not a statement
for (int i = 0, int q = 1; i <= (convert.length()/2 - 1); i++, q++) { 
                             ^
PD.java:28: ')' expected
for (int i = 0, int q = 1; i <= (convert.length()/2 - 1); i++, q++) { 
                                                        ^
PD.java:28: ';' expected
for (int i = 0, int q = 1; i <= (convert.length()/2 - 1); i++, q++) { 
                                                             ^
PD.java:28: ';' expected
for (int i = 0, int q = 1; i <= (convert.length()/2 - 1); i++, q++) {
```

and I'm not sure why it ask to place a ; and why it says it's not a statement

Overall, I get that error and I don't understand why. 
thank you for the help! I know my program maybe incorrect, but I really want to focus on fixing this error. Once again, thank you for your help and time.

Comment: just a comment on your for loop: if q isn't considered in stopping condition of the loop, just put it inside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

The issue appears to be the fact that you have two type identifiers in one statement (e.g. int i, int j;).  When you declare two variables using the same statement, they are implicitly given the same type, so it should be changed to just:

```
for (int i = 0, q = 1; i <= (convert.length()/2 - 1); i++, q++) {
```

Another option is to calculate q from i within the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= (convert.length()/2 - 1); i++) {
    int q = i+1;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change initializers to: `int i = 0, q = 1`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for (int i = 0,; i <= (convert.length()/2 - 1); i++) { 
    if (convert.substring(i,i + 1) == number.substring(number.length() - i + 1, number.length() - i))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a comment on your for loop, q is never considered in the stopping condition, therefore putting it within the loop is more logical in my opinion.

I changed your loop into this:

```
int q = 1;
for (int i = 0; i <= (convert.length()/2 - 1); i++) {
    // code within the loop
    q++;
}
```

Hope it helps you.